# DHTMLX dataProcessor doesnt pick the option value of dropdown(it picks label) when the row is updated but dropdown column is not edited

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dhtmlx

I have a dhtmlx grid with few text fields and a dropdpown(column type:"combo").Dhtmlx dataProcessor is used to serialize and make ajax call to create/update the grid data.XML for dropdown column to load the grid is as below.

```
<column id="artifactType" type="combo" source="/types" filter="true" sort="str" sub="false" width="170">artifactType<option value="type1" >1</option ><option value="type2" >2</option ><option value="type3" >3</option ><option value="type4" >4</option ></column>
```

The problem is if any of the text fields is edited and dropdown is not edited then data Processor is picking the label of dropdowns(ex:1,2,3,4) instead of option values(ex:type1,type2,type3,type4),So its sending wrong payload to the server with labels instead of option values which is failing the server call.Everything works fine if we edit dropdown also(i guess the logic to rewrite payload with option value instead of label might be there in cell editing related events of dhtmlx library),then dataProcessor picks correct values(option values)

its very common scenario that one wants to update only the few text fields of row which also contains dropdowns

Is it the issue with dhtmlx library or dataProcessor ?or am I missing something on configuration side?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the dhtmlxGrid with the dataprocessor and the "combo" column.
Updating any record grid sends the "value" of the combo to server, not the "text", so the updating works well.

Could you please, provide some more details about the using scenario or share a demo link/complete demo, so the problem can be tested locally.